# Create exe that jumps directly into main()-function from C

Tags: c, pe, x64dbg

I am using x64dbg to explore image files on Windows. After the computer finishes prowling ntdll.dll it jumps to OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint.
But this is not my main()-function.

1. What is this code in my EXE that is not mine?
2. Can you remove it so there is only my main()-function remaining?
3. Do you know a way to find the main()-function easily?

Comment: You are looking at CRT initialization. You don't say what toolset you are using but with microsoft tooling, look at the [/ENTRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol) linker flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that runs before your `main` function is the C Runtime (CRT) initialization code. There are ways to remove it, such as via the `/NODEFAULTLIB` and `/ENTRY` command-line options to the linker, but be careful what you wish for. If any of your code calls functions in the C standard library (such as `printf`, `malloc`, etc.), you will not be able to link your code into a final binary unless you provide your own implementations for those functions. Your implementations must be from scratch; you won't be able to rely upon any standard library functions, or implement them using any third-party library that itself relies upon the standard library. This is not a beginner-friendly task, to put it mildly.

To find the `main` function in a binary: first, note that tools such as IDA do this automatically. To do it manually, first familiarize yourself with the CRT functions that execute before `main`, find where it calls `main`. Then, for any given binary, you can locate the address of `main` by examining those CRT functions around the locations where they call `main`.